# How do you handle a RelativeSource binding for a source that may or may not exist?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

We have a control that may or may not be hosted in a popup control.  In the case when it is, we want to set properties on the popup using RelativeSource and OneWayToSource bindings.  In cases where it's not hosted in a popup, we want the binding to basically be ignored/do nothing.

Only thing I can think of is binding to self with a custom converter which internally walks the visual tree looking for the popup. If found, do the magic. If not, do nothing. But I'm wondering if it can be done purely with XAML binding syntax.

Comment: Can you not just set a FallbackValue?

Comment: To what? Again, I don't want it doing anything if the relativesource isn't found.

Comment: Whenever you add a FallbackValue to your binding base you're specifying what happens when the binding fails for any reason.

Comment: I know that, but what do you set it to to mean 'do t do anything'?  That's the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
   <Border>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Exists"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="No stackpanel"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
```

It will display both "No stackpanel" and error in Output window. If you place StackPanel inside Border "Exists" will be displayed. Set anything you wish inside DataTrigger when condition is fulfilled.

**In case you want to avoid receiving error:**

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter x:Key="IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Border>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No StackPanel"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Converter={StaticResource IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Stackpanel exists as parent"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

converter which detects whether such a type is present as a parent:

```
class IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isPresent  = FindParent<StackPanel>((DependencyObject) value);
        return isPresent != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;
        var parent = parentObject as T;
        return parent?? FindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

**And here you have more generic equivalent where you make a use of reflection in order to find parent type.**

```
class IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var method = GetType().GetMethod("FindParent").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[1] { (Type)parameter });
        var foundObject = method.Invoke(this, new object[] { (DependencyObject)value });
        return foundObject != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
        if (parentObject == null) return null;
        var parent = parentObject as T;
        return parent ?? FindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

The only distinction in XAML is that you indicate searching type of object.

```
 <Border>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No StackPanel"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                        Converter={StaticResource IsParentTypePresentToBoolConverter},
                        ConverterParameter={x:Type Border}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Stackpanel exists as parent"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Comment: But that shows as a binding error when there's no stack panel, doesn't it? We do not want binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

> In cases where it's not hosted in a popup, we want the binding to basically be ignored/do nothing.

Since you have a control one can create a Boolean dependency property, a flag,  which can trigger either one of two hidden controls which behaves in a specific way due to which way the boolean is set.

I would call this the standard way, for the control is not required to know anything about the consumer, the consumer specifies the state.

### Or

> to set properties on the popup using RelativeSource and OneWayToSource bindings.

Similar to above, with two distinct hidden controls but then have the a style look for a specific window and a specific property. Then either hide or show the controls depending on what is found:

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPopup, 
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
                 Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                Value="True" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```